# Unable to insert data into mysql in node

Tags: mysql, node.js

Trying to insert data into mysql with `'INSERT INTO users SET ?'`, I get 500 error in front end. data is reaching the server but unable to insert into database. Tried even `'INSERT INTO users VALUES ?'` but still fails. i'm able to retrieve the data from the database('SELECT * FROM users') but not inserting it.

```
router.post('/userstuff', function(req, res, next) {
 var eachuser = {
   name: req.body.name,
   age: req.body.age
 };

  connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',eachuser, function(err, rows){
        if(err) console.log('Error selecting: %s ', err);
        console.log(rows)
  });

});
```

edit: added the schema:

```
 use 02sqldb;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(30),
   age int(2)
  );
```

Comment: What is the schema for the table *users*? Does it have any mandatory column that is not autogenerated? Do you want to check my_sql log files?

Comment: I've added the schema. But i noticed my schema was not working so I have created it manually using `CREATE TABLE users (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name CHAR(25), age INT(2));` then inserted my first data `INSERT INTO users(id, name, age) VALUES (NULL, 'John', '25');`

Answer (score 1):

And what if you try to first do a dummy query. I don't know for sure you can simply put "?" to insert a value without giving a column like

```
'INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES ('?','?','?',...)'
```

If it still isn't working you know it's something else.

Comment: His format works with node.js. He supplies the query with a hash (which has column names and corresponding values).

Comment: i got it. very stupid mistake, i forgot to include the code inside `  req.getConnection(function(err, connection){`